# Testing a React Modal component

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, bootstrap-modal, reactjs

I'm sorry, but I've been having the toughest time trying to test closing my React Modal by clicking a button. The Modal is as simple as can be, and I've tried everything I can think of or find, but I still can't query its children.

The Modal component:

```
var React = require('react');
var Modal = require('react-bootstrap').Modal;
var Button = require('react-bootstrap').Button;

var MyModal = React.createClass({
  ...
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Modal className="my-modal-class" show={this.props.show}>
        <Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Title>My Modal</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          Hello, World!
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
});
```

My goal is to test if that Close button fires the `onHide()` function when it is clicked.

My test file:

```
describe('MyModal.jsx', function() {
  it('tests the Close Button', function() {
    var spy = sinon.spy();
    var MyModalComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <MyModal show onHide={spy}/>
    );

    // This passes
    TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(MyModalComponent, MyModal);

    // This fails
    var CloseButton = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(MyModalComponent, 'button');

    // Never gets here
    TestUtils.Simulate.click(CloseButton);
    expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

No matter what I try, I can't seem to find the Close Button.

Comment: Are you using jest? I haven't ever used jest, but I think it auto-mocks the dependent components. Can that be the issue?

Comment: @AbhishekJain I am using Mocha

Comment: is `<Button>` a user defined class or are you trying to do `<button>`?

Comment: @HenrikAndersson I should clarify that's part of React-Bootstrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit testing React Bootstrap modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655466/unit-testing-react-bootstrap-modal-dialog)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Martoid_Prime/69z2wepo/31164/) using the [React Base Fiddle (JSX)](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/) to find out what was going on in your test (I created my own 'spy' that simply logged to the console when called).

I found out that the reason you can't find your button is because it doesn't exist where you might expect it to.

The [Bootstrap Modal Component](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Modal.js) (`<Modal/>`) is actually contained within a [React-Overlays](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-overlays) modal component (called `BaseModal` in the code, which is from [here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-overlays/blob/master/src/Modal.js)). This in turn renders a component called `Portal` whose [render method](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-overlays/blob/master/src/Portal.js) simply returns `null`. It is this `null` value you are trying to find rendered components on.

Due to the modal not being rendered the traditional React way, React cannot see the modal in order to use `TestUtils` on. An entirely seperate `<div/>` child node is placed in the `document` body and this new `<div/>` is used to build the modal.

So, in order to allow you to simulate a click using React's `TestUtils` (the click handler on the button is still bound to the button's click event), you can use standard JS methods to search the DOM instead. Set up your test as follows:

```
describe('MyModal.jsx', function() {
  it('tests the Close Button', function() {
    var spy = sinon.spy();
    var MyModalComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <MyModal show onHide={spy}/>
    );

    // This passes
    TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(MyModalComponent, MyModal);

    // This will get the actual DOM node of the button
    var closeButton = document.body.getElementsByClassName("my-modal-class")[0].getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default")[0];

    // Will now get here
    TestUtils.Simulate.click(CloseButton);
    expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

The function `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements with that class so you must take the first one  (and in your test case, your only one) from each collection.

Your test should now pass ^_^

Comment: `findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag` fails because it finds 0 instead of 1 :(

Comment: Oh no! I thought I had it! I'll leave this here for now but I'll keep working on it. I'll edit my answer when I find something new =)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new solution. Let me know if you have any problems =)

Comment: I was having an almost identical issue and this solution worked for me. It should be marked as correct IMO.

Comment: This works!  I spent 2 hours trying to figure out what is wrong with my test. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I ended up going with. It stubs the way React renders a Modal to just render a `<div>` instead.

`test-utils.js`:

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var React = require('react');
var Modal = require('react-bootstrap').Modal;

module.exports = {
  stubModal: function() {
    var createElement = React.createElement;
    modalStub = sinon.stub(React, 'createElement', function(elem) {
      return elem === Modal ?
        React.DOM.div.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1)) :
        createElement.apply(this, arguments);
    });
    return modalStub;
  },
  stubModalRestore: function() {
    if (modalStub) {
      modalStub.restore();
      modalStub = undefined;
    } else {
      console.error('Cannot restore nonexistent modalStub');
    }
  }
};
```

`modal-test.jsx`

```
var testUtils = require('./test-utils');

describe('test a Modal!', function() {
  before(testUtils.stubModal);
  after(testUtils.stubModalRestore);

  it('renders stuff', function() {
    var MyModalComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <MyModal show/>
    );
    // Do more stuff you normally expect you can do
  });
});
```