# React - Owner Ownee Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

Trying to use React's Test-Utils (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html) to test my component.

We have Owner and Ownee.

Owner renders:

```
<Ownee>
    <div class="inner"> 
        <div class="moreInner" />
    </div>
</Ownee>
```

My test is like such:

```
var comp = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Owner />);
var innerClass = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(comp, "inner");
expect(innterClass).to.not.be.null;
```

Ideally, this should work fine.  But actually, it outputs: "Did not find exactly one match (found: 0)".

So if I remove the `<Ownee></Ownee>` above so it's like:

```
    <div class="inner"> 
        <div class="moreInner" />
    </div>
```

It works as expected, but I can't use this (Must render the Ownee element too).

Ownee renders something like so:

```
<div class="inner"> 
    {this.props.children}
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to use TestUtils to get the desired result (That is the test working and finding the div by class)?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `className` **not** class

Comment: Am doing, mis-type simplifying code.

Comment: If ownee renders the className inner, why are you also manually adding it inbetween the ownee tags? Could you just show the render() for ownee and  owner un modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem wasn't owner/ownee.  It ended up being that I was using React-Bootstrap's modal dialog (As the Ownee).  So what happened was the test would render the component, but it would be put on a different component tree.

To get around this, I followed a question previously asked:
[Testing a React Modal component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086297/testing-a-react-modal-component)

Specifically, user1778856's answer.

```
var stubModal = () => {
    var createElement = React.createElement;
    modalStub = sinon.stub(React, 'createElement', function (elem: any) {
        return elem === ModalDialog ?
            React.DOM.div.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1)) :
            createElement.apply(this, arguments);
    });
    return modalStub;
};
var stubModalRestore = () => {
    if (modalStub) {
        modalStub.restore();
        modalStub = undefined;
    } else {
        console.error('Cannot restore nonexistent modalStub');
    }
};

before(() => { stubModal(); });
after(() => { stubModalRestore(); });
```

Other links:
[Unit testing React Bootstrap modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655466/unit-testing-react-bootstrap-modal-dialog)