# Content of React modal dialogs is not available to Enzyme tests using mount()

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, modal-dialog, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component with a modal dialog (built using `reactstrap`, but others have reported similar problems with `react-bootstrap` and other types of modal components). Enzyme cannot find any of the components inside the modal, even though they render fine in the actual app. Minimal example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Modal } from 'reactstrap'

export default class MyModal extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="outside"> Some elements outside of the dialog </div>
            <Modal isOpen={this.props.modalOpen}>
                <div className="inside"> Content of dialog </div>
            </Modal>
         );
    } 
}
```

I would like to test the contents (in this case using `jest`) like this

```
import React from 'react'
import MyModal  from './MyModal'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

it('renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount( <MyModal modalOpen/> );

    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();

    // Passes
    expect(wrapper.find('.outside')).toHaveLength(1);

    // Fails, 0 length
    expect(wrapper.find('.inside')).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

The test finds the contents outside of the Modal correctly, but does not find anything inside. Looking at the snapshot shows that, indeed, nothing inside the `<Modal>` is rendered. However it does work if I replace `mount` with `shallow`. The problem with that is I need `mount` to test lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount`.

Why doesn't `mount` render the contents of the modal? I thought the whole point was that it rendered the entire tree of child elements.

Comment: Checkout answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57642968/1802179

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: This is no longer a problem in React 16 + Enzyme 3, because [React 16 supports portal components](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).

In React 15 and before, the problem is that a modal dialog is (in most implementations) a [portal](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal) component. This means it creates DOM elements that are attached directly to the document root, rather than being children of the parent React component.

The `find` method of the [`ReactWrapper`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) created by `mount` looks through the DOM starting with the element created by the top level component, so it can't find the contents of the modal. But Enzyme's `shallow` doesn't attach to a DOM, and instead builds its own component tree which contains the modal contents.

To test a portal component, you first need to find the DOM elements that have been attached to the document body. Then you can create a new `ReactWrapper` around them so that all the usual Enzyme functions work:

```
import React from 'react'
import MyModal  from './MyModal'
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from 'enzyme'

it('renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount( <MyModal modalOpen/> );

    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();

    // Passes
    expect(wrapper.find('.outside')).toHaveLength(1);

    // Construct new wrapper rooted at modal content
    inside_els = document.getElementsByClassName("inside")[0]
    inside_wrapper = new ReactWrapper(inside_els, true)

    // Passes
    expect(inside_wrapper.find('.inside')).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Currently, this is an [open bug](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/252) in Enzyme.

Update: It seems that Enzyme also leaves the modal attached to the DOM after the test finishes, so you may end up with multiple dialogs open in a later test. If this is a problem, you can clear the DOM after each test like this:

```
afterEach(() => {
  var node = global.document.body;
  while (node.firstChild) {
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
  }
});
```

Comment: can you share how your posted solution would change after React 16 supports portal components?  I'm using React 16 and I'm still having this issue

Answer (score 1):

try mocking the createPortal responsible for showing modals  `ReactDOM.createPortal = jest.fn(modal => modal);`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using an older version of Enzyme, you can pass the container element to `mount` where you want your `Modal` to be rendered, like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import MyModal  from './MyModal'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

describe(() => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => {
        const container = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(container);
        wrapper = mount( <MyModal modalOpen/> , {attachTo: container});
    });

    it('renders correctly', () => {
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();

        // Passes
        expect(wrapper.find('.outside')).toHaveLength(1);

        // Passes now
        expect(wrapper.find('.inside')).toHaveLength(1);
    });

})
```