# Content of Reactstrap Modal is not visible to jest mount

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, reactstrap

I have build a component in react based on reactstrap then using jest and Enzyme  I am unable to test the content of modal. Let's see what I have tried so far:

```
import React from 'react';
 import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';

    class ModalExample extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          modal: false
        };

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
      }

      toggle() {
        this.setState({
          modal: !this.state.modal
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="modal-testing">
            <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>{this.props.buttonLabel}</Button>
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
              <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
              <ModalBody className="inside">
                I just want this to show up in unit test
                Name: <input type="text" />
              </ModalBody>
              <ModalFooter>
                <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
                <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
              </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default ModalExample;
```

And I have its unit tests as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount, ReactWrapper} from "enzyme";
import ModalExample from "./ModalExample";

const wrapper = mount(
    <ModalExample isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
);
const button = wrapper.find('Button').at(0);
button.simulate('click');
// What I have tried
expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('I just want this to show up in unit test');
expect(wrapper.find('input')).toHaveLength(1); // it gets failed
```

By the way, I have already tried this method, but it didn't worked:

[Similar issue posted on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644244/content-of-react-modal-dialogs-is-not-available-to-enzyme-tests-using-mount)

But I don't know what am I doing wrong, could anyone spot any error or correct me if something not at proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found that this was actually [reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap) library issue as I was using an old version i.e. "reactstrap": "5.0.0-beta", so I just updated [reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap) library to its latest version: "reactstrap": "^6.5.0" and it worked.

Thank you @Herman for you time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ModalExample` does not render it's `children` prop, so `<p>Hello world</p>` is essentially ignored. Why are you passing it in?

Comment: Okay, let me remove that <p> tag, but still, I am unable to render children in my test?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using an older version of Enzyme/ReactStrap, you can pass the container element to mount where you want your Modal to be rendered, like this:

```
Actual Code:
------------
import React from 'react'
import { Modal } from 'reactstrap'

export default MyModal = () => {
    return (
        <Modal isOpen={props.isOpen}>
            <ModalHeader>Header</ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>Body</ModalBody>
        </Modal>
     );
} 

Unit Test:
----------
import React from 'react'
import MyModal  from './MyModal'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

describe(() => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => {
        const container = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(container);
        wrapper = mount( <MyModal isOpen={true}/> , {attachTo: container});
    });

    it('renders correctly', () => {
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();

        expect(wrapper.find('ModalHeader')).toHaveLength(1);

        expect(wrapper.find('ModalBody')).toHaveLength(1);
    });

});
```